# How to get a numerical result

Tags: equation-solving

I'd like to express a numerical value of h c/k T. The below does only show me the equation, but not the actual value. Any suggestions how I can achieve it would be greatly apprecaited.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
h = Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"];
c = Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"] ;
k = Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"];

\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(\[AliasDelimiter]\)]\) = 
  Quantity[7200, "Kelvin"];

\[Lambda] == h c/k T 
UnitConvert[\[Lambda], "meters"] // N
```

[image]

Comment: replace the ‘==‘ with ‘=‘ and re-evaluate

Comment: still getting UnitConvert[
 T (Quantity[1, ("PlanckConstant" "SpeedOfLight")/(
    "BoltzmannConstant")]), "meter"]

Comment: looks like you haven’t defined T

Comment: hit shift enter on your cell containing T=...

Comment: Also replace “meters” with “Meters”

Comment: you're right. thanks works now